# sum of digits in different bases

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given a natural number, what is the maximal natural number below it, whose sums of digits in base 10 and base 2 are the same?
Is there a clever algorithm to do this aside from the brute force search?

Comment: But why do you interest in this problem?I think this problem does not make much sense.

Comment: @Hecke, which part of the question does it not make sense?

Comment: It is connected with decimal,which makes it's hard to solve it with pure mathematical methods.That's my opinion,but if you just want a good algorithm to get it,you will find one..

Comment: Note that you can put a bound on the sum in base 2. For example, looking at three digit numbers base 10, note that 2^10 > n for all 3 digit numbers, so the sum of digits in base 2 must be 10 or less. Now you can rule out some 3 digit numbers base 10.

Comment: See also, http://oeis.org/A037308

Comment: @Hecke, so it does make sense mathematically. Do you agree? Yes, it is hard to solve. Otherwise, I would not have posted the question here. Do you have some useful information to contribute?

Comment: @JoshB., thank you for the link. But that is brute force enumeration. I am asking for a more clever way.

Comment: @Hans I thought the link might be a place to get started, find some patterns, ect. Though my previous comment should help you not have to search though quite every number.

Comment: @JoshB. I do appreciate the link. But before I posted the question, I already wrote a short code enumerating the sequence to any given upper bound, same as accompanying code on the sequence web page does.

Comment: @JoshB. I just saw your first comment. I considered that when I first looked at the problem. It will cut down the case when searching, but we need some better filter to pare down the possibilities much further.

Comment: I was investigating something when I met with a variant of this question. Do we even know if there exists an infinite number of numbers which satisfy the condition if no upper bound is given?

Comment: @the4seasons: Good question. Let me think about it.